# display loading animation while slow algorithm work AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I want to display loading animation at the page while algorithm works. How can I do it using angular promises? For example :

```
<div ng-hide='algEnded' > Content to hide while alg. works</div>
<div ng-hide='!algEnded' > <img href='img/loading.svg'> </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the JS code?

Comment: yes, but partially (it's too large)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yL8m822g/ just for examle - it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) for time consuming tasks.

```
angular.module('myModule').service(myService);

function myService($q){

    function calculate(){
         return $q(function(resolve, reject){
              var myWorker = new Worker("myTask.js");

              myWorker.onmessage = function (e) {
                  resolve(e.data);  //resolve promise when worker posts data
                  myWorker.terminate();
              };
         });
    }

    this.calculate = calculate;
}

angular.module('myModule').controller(MyController);

function MyController(myService){
     var vm = this;

     this.calculate = function(){
          algEnded = false;
          myService.calculate().then(function(){
               algEnded = true;
          });
    }
}
```

modify your html like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
    <div ng-hide='vm.algEnded' > Content to hide while alg. works</div>
    <div ng-hide='!vm.algEnded' > <img href='img/loading.svg'> </div>
</div>
```

and put your algorithm in  myTask.js

```
function algorithm(){
    return 1+1;
}


postMessage(algorithm());
```

Comment: so, is it possible to make it async with promises? Maybe I dont understand promises "mission" in JS? Is it was created for time consuming tasks and to not block UI for example?

Comment: Exacly,  task in web worker will be performed asynchronously and so it  will not block UI nor show any "Unresponsive Script" popup.

Answer (score 0):

In every project we use [angular-loading-bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar) plugin.

You just add it as a dependency to your module and it will automatically add an interceptor to all XHR requests.

You can check examples here:

https://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/